# Webpack and Babel returning Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack to bundle my react webapp and my nodejs server. My react webapp bundles fine (I am using import statements). However, when I try to add an import statement in my nodejs server, I get the following error.

The error:

```
.../server/app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Account from "./models/Account.js";
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/.../start.js:41:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict";

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

let nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync("node_modules")
    .filter(function(x) {
        return [".bin"].indexOf(x) === -1;
    })
    .forEach(function(mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = "commonjs " + mod;
    });

module.exports = [{
    name: "client",
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: "./src/app.js",
    output: {
        path: "./static/bin",
        filename: "app.bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: /src/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
            }
        },{
            test:/\.scss$/,
            include: /src/,
            loaders: ["style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap"]
        }]
    }
},{
    name: "server",
    target: "node",
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: "./server/app.js",
    output: {
        path: "./server",
        filename: "build.js"
    },
    externals: nodeModules,
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: /server/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
            }
        },{
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: "json-loader"
        }]
    }
}];
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "start.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --use_strict start.js",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "postinstall": "webpack --display-error-details"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "eslint": "^2.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-graphql": "^0.5.3",
    "graphql": "^0.6.0",
    "graphql-relay": "^0.4.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.9",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-relay": "^0.9.0",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried `npm update` and removing and reinstalling my node_modules folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: That error message makes it sound like you're running `server/app.js` directly, are you accidentally running that instead of your `server/build.js`?

Comment: I knew there was going to be a stupid reason for this! I forgot to change the start.js script to point to build.js instead of app.js. If you move your comment to an answer I would be happy to mark it as the accepted one. Thank you so much!